# CKEditor custom styles from file not showing

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I can't seem to add **my own** CSS file to the CKEditor. I'm downloading a custom version 4.5.8 and include the ["StyleSheet Parser" plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylesheetparser). The "Styles" list has the default styles, but not the ones from my css file.

This the code:

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '../../../css/test.css';

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

The editor is loaded successfully, but the "Styles" list does not contain my styles. The location of my css files seems right, when I try other paths I get an error.

This is my test.css:

```
.testStyle {
    color: red;
    font-family: "Arial Black", arial-black;
}
```

Already tried clearing my browsers cache. I tried it in multiple browsers.

I tried one other thing: download the StyleSheet Parser separately, put it in the plugins folder, and use the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '../../../css/test.css';
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

The "Styles" list is still not showing my style, but when I edit the source code and put my style in like this, the style is applied to the text in the editor(!):

```
<p class="testStyle">Test text</p>
```

Sources:

[- CKEditor docs for the StyleSheet Parser](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles-section-the-stylesheet-parser-plugin)

[- The "contentsCss" option docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Styles in CKEditor require an element, so the StyleSheetParser only recognizes rules that include an element and a class name.
You should change your CSS to

```
p.testStyle {
    color: red;
    font-family: "Arial Black", arial-black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm curious if (and where) this is documented?

Comment: I guess that it's documented across different pages, answers to this same question, ...

Comment: This does not appear to be the case any more in CKEditor 4.11.1. On the other hand, whoever has the same problem should as a first step try to switch to standard preset and, if that works, try to identify the conflicting plugin, see my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906416/style-not-loaded-in-ckeditor-plugin/