# Style not loaded in CKEditor plugin

Tags: ckeditor

I am developing a CKEditor widget. I followed and adapted the [widget tutorial](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1.html), then tried to add a style using `addContentsCss`, as specified in the [plugin sdk styles](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_styles.html), but the styles are not loaded. I used the browser console to analyze the situation, and I found out that my style, `odtbox.css`, is present in `CKEDITOR.instances.editor.config.contentsCss`:

[image: Browser console screenshot]

but it is not loaded by the page:

[image]

I can click on the path shown in the console for my css and it is correctly shown. Permissions for the file are correct - they are equal to those of the files that are loaded. What else can I check?

Comment: While debugging the problem I switched to standard preset from the one I was using, which includes a number of plugins which I thought may be useful, and the problem disappeared. As soon as I can I will try to add the plugins one by one and check which one is causing problems. Funny thing is, the problem appears even if I _do not load_ any additional plugin, it's enaough that they are present in the distribution... so I guess it should be a bug. I'll update this question as soon as I have news.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after finding the solution, it was quite obvious – the problem was also that I had dowoloaded my custom bundle when I still had no experience with CKEditor, and then quickly forgot what had happened, and then the guilty plugin did not appear in `plugins/` for the optimized package. It was [divarea](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea), whose description clearly states:

> This plugin uses a  element (instead of the traditional  element) as the editable area in the themedui creator. Much similar to inline editing, it benefits from allowing the editor content to inherit from host page styles.

Without this plugin, styles are correctly applied, even without taking into account the solution to a similar problem given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827393/ckeditor-custom-styles-from-file-not-showing); I guess that depends on the specific version, I am using the latest version of ckeditor 4 available at the moment (4.11.1).